# Oracle pluggable database rename and TNSNAMES.ORA file editting

Tags: oracle

I have renamed pluggable database with the following set of commands:

```
conn / as sysdba;
alter pluggable database ORCLPDB1 close;
alter pluggable database ORCLPDB1 open restricted;
alter session set container=ORCLPDB1;
alter pluggable database rename global_name to NEW_NAME;
alter pluggable database close immediate;
alter pluggable database open;
show pdbs;
```

and see that PDB has been renamed successfully:

```
$ lsnrctl status
...
Service "new_name" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

and I can connect to PDB with a new name with a string

```
sqlplus sys@localhost:1521/NEW_NAME as sysdba
```

But I see no changes in tnsnames.ora file after rename:

```
ORCLCDB=localhost:1521/ORCLCDB
ORCLPDB1= 
(DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLPDB1)
  )
)
```

So I can not understand what I need this file for if I can connect to PDB with a new name without a problem and should I change ORCLPDB1 to NEW_NAME in this file manually?

Comment: Regarding posted contents of `tnsnames.ora` file: first row is not needed, and in fact is syntax error (`ORCLCDB=localhost:1521/ORCLCDB`). And contents of `tnsnames.ora` is not updated automatically when you rename PDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have used for connection in that example:

```
sqlplus sys@localhost:1521/NEW_NAME as sysdba
```

... is called Easy Connect or EZ Connect, and do not use alias defined in `tnsnames.ora`. Because in such type of connection already used all 3 required pieces of information - Hostname (`localhost` in your case), Port (`1521`) and Service Name (`NEW_NAME`).

In order to use connection via `tnsnames.ora` (called Local Naming as opposite to EZ) - you should use:

```
sqlplus sys@ORCLPDB1 as sysdba
```

... where `ORCLPDB1` is alias defined in your posted `tnsnames.ora`.